# Use initializer list to initialize new vector

Tags: c++

So I have this big map of vectors, you can see I use an initializer list to initialize the vectors.
However, although this works it really doesn't seem like it should, if you create an empty vector and try to use the `=` operator and then assign it to an initializer list you get the error "too many values in initializer list" but for some reason when you try to do the same with a map of vectors it just... works. However the issue is of course these are allocated on the stack and quickly causes a stack overflow so the goal would be to find a way to use initializer list (or something of similar brevity) to initialize these vectors on the heap.
Example code causing stack over flow below

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
struct IVector2 {
    int x;
    int y;
};
struct animation_frame_t {
    IVector2 position;
    IVector2 size;
};
std::map<std::string, std::vector<animation_frame_t>> animations;
void initAnimations() {
    animations["boss_andromeda_attack_"] = { {{303,101},{100,100}}, {{606,101},{100,100}}, {{606,0},{100,100}}, {{505,909},{100,100}}, {{505,808},{100,100}}, {{505,707},{100,100}}, {{505,606},{100,100}}, {{505,505},{100,100}}, {{505,404},{100,100}}, {{505,303},{100,100}}, {{505,202},{100,100}}, {{505,101},{100,100}}, {{505,0},{100,100}}, {{404,909},{100,100}}, {{404,808},{100,100}}, {{404,707},{100,100}}, {{404,606},{100,100}}, {{404,505},{100,100}}, {{404,404},{100,100}}, {{404,303},{100,100}}, {{404,202},{100,100}}, {{404,101},{100,100}}, {{404,0},{100,100}} };
    animations["boss_andromeda_breathing_"] = { {{303,909},{100,100}}, {{303,808},{100,100}}, {{303,707},{100,100}}, {{303,606},{100,100}}, {{303,505},{100,100}}, {{303,505},{100,100}}, {{303,404},{100,100}}, {{303,303},{100,100}}, {{303,202},{100,100}}, {{606,202},{100,100}} };
    animations["boss_andromeda_death_"] = { {{303,0},{100,100}}, {{202,909},{100,100}}, {{202,808},{100,100}}, {{202,707},{100,100}}, {{202,606},{100,100}}, {{202,505},{100,100}}, {{202,404},{100,100}}, {{202,303},{100,100}}, {{202,202},{100,100}}, {{202,101},{100,100}}, {{202,0},{100,100}}, {{101,909},{100,100}}, {{101,808},{100,100}} };
    animations["boss_andromeda_hit_"] = { {{303,0},{100,100}}, {{202,909},{100,100}}, {{202,808},{100,100}} };
    animations["boss_andromeda_idle_"] = { {{101,707},{100,100}}, {{101,606},{100,100}}, {{101,505},{100,100}}, {{101,404},{100,100}}, {{101,303},{100,100}}, {{101,202},{100,100}}, {{101,101},{100,100}}, {{101,0},{100,100}}, {{0,909},{100,100}}, {{0,808},{100,100}} };
    animations["boss_andromeda_run_"] = { {{0,707},{100,100}}, {{0,606},{100,100}}, {{0,505},{100,100}}, {{0,404},{100,100}}, {{0,303},{100,100}}, {{0,202},{100,100}}, {{0,101},{100,100}}, {{0,0},{100,100}} };
    animations["boss_antiswarm_attack_"] = { {{393,1310},{130,130}}, {{917,655},{130,130}}, {{917,524},{130,130}}, {{917,393},{130,130}}, {{917,262},{130,130}}, {{917,131},{130,130}}, {{917,0},{130,130}}, {{786,1834},{130,130}}, {{786,1703},{130,130}}, {{786,1572},{130,130}}, {{786,1441},{130,130}}, {{786,1310},{130,130}}, {{786,1179},{130,130}}, {{786,1048},{130,130}}, {{786,917},{130,130}}, {{786,786},{130,130}}, {{786,655},{130,130}}, {{786,524},{130,130}}, {{786,393},{130,130}}, {{786,262},{130,130}}, {{786,131},{130,130}}, {{786,0},{130,130}}, {{655,1834},{130,130}}, {{655,1703},{130,130}}, {{655,1572},{130,130}}, {{655,1441},{130,130}}, {{655,1310},{130,130}}, {{655,1179},{130,130}}, {{655,1048},{130,130}}, {{655,917},{130,130}}, {{655,786},{130,130}}, {{655,655},{130,130}}, {{655,524},{130,130}}, {{655,393},{130,130}}, {{655,262},{130,130}}, {{655,131},{130,130}}, {{655,0},{130,130}}, {{524,1834},{130,130}}, {{524,1703},{130,130}}, {{524,1572},{130,130}}, {{524,1441},{130,130}}, {{524,1310},{130,130}}, {{524,1179},{130,130}} };
    animations["boss_antiswarm_breathing_"] = { {{524,1048},{130,130}}, {{524,917},{130,130}}, {{524,786},{130,130}}, {{524,655},{130,130}}, {{524,524},{130,130}}, {{524,393},{130,130}}, {{524,262},{130,130}}, {{524,131},{130,130}}, {{524,0},{130,130}}, {{393,1834},{130,130}}, {{393,1703},{130,130}}, {{393,1572},{130,130}}, {{393,1441},{130,130}}, {{917,786},{130,130}} };
    animations["boss_antiswarm_death_"] = { {{393,1179},{130,130}}, {{393,1048},{130,130}}, {{393,917},{130,130}}, {{393,786},{130,130}}, {{393,655},{130,130}}, {{393,524},{130,130}}, {{393,393},{130,130}}, {{393,262},{130,130}}, {{393,131},{130,130}}, {{393,0},{130,130}}, {{262,1834},{130,130}}, {{262,1703},{130,130}}, {{262,1572},{130,130}}, {{262,1441},{130,130}}, {{262,1310},{130,130}}, {{262,1179},{130,130}}, {{262,1048},{130,130}}, {{262,917},{130,130}}, {{262,786},{130,130}}, {{262,655},{130,130}}, {{262,524},{130,130}}, {{262,393},{130,130}}, {{262,262},{130,130}}, {{262,131},{130,130}}, {{262,0},{130,130}}, {{131,1834},{130,130}}, {{131,1703},{130,130}} };
    animations["boss_antiswarm_hit_"] = { {{131,1572},{130,130}}, {{131,1441},{130,130}}, {{131,1310},{130,130}} };
    //40k more lines of code
```

Comment: Is this the proper way to load that ? By hardcoding 40K lines of code? How about storing all that in a resource/file/database?

Comment: Can you paste the stack trace when you get a stack overflow in your debugger?  Is there a line which has way more points than in your posted example code?  Because your example seems to have maybe 100 elements per line of code, which should not overflow the stack.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63296606/2-d-array-too-many-initializer-values-warning-error

Comment: @MichaelChourdakis Probably not, still though, It would be nice to know a bit more about how to use initializer list, not even 100% sure why they are allowed here

Comment: @AniketRay Interesting, so initializer list can be used for... well initialization but can't be used for assignment, the question then is how can I tell C++ I want this vector to be a NEW vector

Comment: @JohnZwinck Only other thing on the stack is main right now

Comment: I should add, the largest vector created in this entire file is the
"boss_antiswarm_breathing_" line